# How can I get an icon for my RSS feed?

Tags: rss, icons

And by icon I mean an icon which would be used in for example Google Reader. I suppose I have to add a child element of some sort to my `<channel>`, but can't quite figure it out...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your website has a favicon.ico then Google Reader will automatically load the icon.

**Note:** The favicon must be found at the `example.com/favicon.ico` root folder location.

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but doesn't it just use the favicon?

I'm basing this on the initial release note: http://googlereader.blogspot.com/2009/11/let-your-subscriptions-personality-come.html

Comment: The favicon of my website, or do you mean to define a favicon in the feed xml?