# how to add url icon on rss site

Tags: php, rss

I have a working RSS Feed on my site using the code below but what I would like to add is to have my personal icon to show on the the url address bar in the browser.

```
<?php define ('CONFIG_SYSTEM_URL','http://www.mydomain.tk/');

require_once('feedcreator/feedcreator.class.php');

$feedformat='RSS2.0';

header('Content-type: application/xml');

$rss = new UniversalFeedCreator();
$rss->useCached();
$rss->title = "daily news feed";
$rss->cssStyleSheet='';
$rss->description = 'this feed is from me';
$rss->link = CONFIG_SYSTEM_URL;
$rss->syndicationURL = CONFIG_SYSTEM_URL.'feed.php';

$articles=new itemList();  
foreach ($articles as $i) {   
    $item = new FeedItem();
    $item->title = sprintf('%s',$i->title);
    $item->link = CONFIG_SYSTEM_URL.'item.php?id='.$i->dbId;
    $item->description = $i->Subject;   
    $item->date = $i->ModifyDate;   
    $item->source = CONFIG_SYSTEM_URL;   
    $item->author = $i->User;
    $rss->addItem($item);
}

print $rss->createFeed($feedformat);

?>
```

The code below work on other PHP pages if I add in the  area but if I add that to the RSS page there's an error. If I am not mistaken it is because the RSS is being rendered as XML?

> ```
> <head>
> <title>Other page works with icon but rss wont</title>
> <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/myicon.ico">
> </head>
> ```

Anyone can help me on how to change the icon on URL bar if on RSS? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8782782/how-can-i-get-an-icon-for-my-rss-feed

Comment: Hi steve, before I posted, I already tried the favicon.ico thing but seems it is not the solution. I have my favico.ico in the root directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here i am explaining the  tag which can be inserted in your main channel and set aside with Text description.

```
<image> sub-element of <channel> 

<image> is an optional sub-element of <channel>, which contains three required and three optional sub-elements.

<url> is the URL of a GIF, JPEG or PNG image that represents the channel.

<title> describes the image, it's used in the ALT attribute of the HTML <img> tag when the channel is rendered in HTML.

<link> is the URL of the site, when the channel is rendered, the image is a link to the site. (Note, in practice the image <title> and <link> should have the same value as the channel's <title> and <link>.

Optional elements include <width> and <height>, numbers, indicating the width and height of the image in pixels. <description> contains text that is included in the TITLE attribute of the link formed around the image in the HTML rendering.

Maximum value for width is 144, default value is 88.

Maximum value for height is 400, default value is 31.

<image>
    <url>http://www.snook.ca/img/rss_banner.gif</url>
    <title>Snook.ca</title>
    <link>http://www.snook.ca/jonathan/</link>
    <width>111</width>
    <height>32</height>
    <description>Snook.ca features tips, tricks, and bookmarks on web development</description>
  </image>
```

you can try this out with your dynamic code.

Comment: Hi Amit, thanks for the suggestion. I think I confused you with my question about the icon.

What i mean about the icon is the URL icon showing on the URL bar and not an image on the RSS. I have the image feature on my RSS which I didn't include but for reference I will provide.

`code`
$image = new FeedImage();
$image->title = 'My Personal RSS Logo';
$image->url = 'http://www.mydomain.tk/images/mypersonallogo.png';
$image->link = "http://www.mydomain.tk";
$image->description = 'This is my personal RSS logo';
$image->width = 20;
$image->height = 20;
$rss->image = $image;
`code`